# Session being reset by django-all auth

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication, django-sessions

I am using [django all auth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) for login on my website. I want to pass some session variables from one view to the other, but when I go to login page through allauth, my session variable is somehow being reset. Is the session being destroyed when I go to the login page?
If yes, how can I pass my variables from one view to the other?

## view1

```
  request.session['redirect-url'] = request.get_full_path()
  path = request.session['redirect-url']
```

## view2 (in login view )

```
 session_url = request.session.get('redirect-url' , None)
 if session_url:
     success_url = session_url
     del request.session['redirect-url']
```

I also check this session variable on other pages of my site and it is being passed correctly. But is being reset when i got to my login page. Why?

I have checked the `login` view and there is no explicit statement that clears the session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because you define `del` in your login view. `del` clears the session variable.

```
session_url = resquest.session.get('redirect-url' , None)
if session_url:
    success_url = session_url
```